# Does sp_dropextendedproc drop both system-defined and user-defined extended stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I'm a student and the SQL Server 2016 documentation that I'm going through is not very clear. And the online help that I saw I think it refers to SQL Server 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dropextendedproc-transact-sql

Regards

Comment: The article says `Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version).` right near the top.

Comment: @Equalsk: the article also specifically mentions SQL Server 2017, so don't be too harsh.

Answer (score 1):

The article says

> In SQL Server 2017, `sp_dropextendedproc` does not drop system
>   extended stored procedures. Instead, the system administrator should deny
>   `EXECUTE` permission on the extended stored procedure to the `public` role.

Which is true, but seems to suggest this is something new in SQL Server 2017. This is not the case; it's an inappropriate search-replace based on the current version. The Books Online help for SQL Server 2005 (since removed online, I think) says this (emphasis mine):

> In SQL Server 2005, `sp_dropextendedproc` does not drop system extended
>   stored procedures. Instead, the system administrator should deny
>   `EXECUTE` permission on the extended stored procedure to the `public`
>   role. **In SQL Server 2000, `sp_dropextendedproc` could be used to drop
>   any extended stored procedure.**

And this, unlike the current version, makes it clear what's going on. Sometimes Microsoft's obsession with removing documentation for products that are no longer supported goes a little too far.